# google app script for sheets - select multiple list values and record in same cell

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to replicate something I was able to do in Excel in Google Sheets: Select multiple list values and record in same cell.

I used this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x6YUsl7Ld4&feature=youtu.be

And this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from www.trumpexcel.com
' To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

And managed to get it working in Excel, only to find that the functionality would be lost in Google Sheets.

Please could you tell me the equivalent code in Google apps script and where to place it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the script to do the same through google-apps-script. Caveats though are
  1. Data Validation should be enabled to `Show warning` and not `Reject Input` as shown below
[image]
  2. After selecting multiple items, the Cell in consideration would show a warning.(I couldn't figure out how to turn this off easily).One way to lessen the annoying warning on the cell is to put a help context for the cell *"Ignore any warnings"* by checking the box `Show validation help text:` in the image above.
  3. The behavior is applied to **ALL** ranges where there is data validation, so please take due care to apply **ONLY** to ranges that you care about.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var editedRange=e.range;
  var rule = editedRange.getDataValidation();
  if(rule!=null) //Act only if the cell has a data validation
    if (!(e.value.equals("") || e.oldValue == null)) //No need to do anything funky if user clears everything or if previous contents were empty
      if(e.oldValue.indexOf(e.value) !=-1) //Check if new selected value has already been chosen before 
        editedRange.setValue(e.oldValue) //If already chosen then don't select again.
      else
        editedRange.setValue(e.oldValue+","+e.value) // Show old+new selection.
}
```

`onEdit` is a Simple trigger function that gets called every time there is an edit to the Spreadsheet(any individual `Sheet`s ).
`e` is the  `Event Object` that contains information about the edit that happened.
You can find more documentation about the same [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).
Also [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation) might help if you want to programmatically set a Data Validation.

Comment: ¿How can I apply this only for one colum?

Comment: @xav56883728 make sure in the image above, it is showing `Sheet1!A:A`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dialog to show every available option as checkboxes and set the cell data based on the user selection.

Here is some example data:

[image: data]

and here how such dialog would behave:

[image: dialog]

To do that you must first create a script file with four functions. One to expose a menu to the dialog, another to show the dialog, a third to process and pass the options to the dialog, and the last one to set data in the cell sent from the dialog. See the code bellow:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const multiselectMenu = {name: 'Select multiple', functionName: 'showSelectDialog'}
  ss.addMenu("My Scripts", [multiselectMenu]);
}

function showSelectDialog(){
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dialog');
  template.optionsData = getOptionsFromCurrentCell();
  const html = template.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select multiple');
}

function getOptionsFromCurrentCell(){
  const validOptions = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveRange() // everything that is selected
    .getDataValidation() // all validation rules for that
    .getCriteriaValues()[0] // the first criteria
    .getValues() // the value for this criteria
    .map(value => value[0]); // flatten in an one dimension array

  const selectedOptions = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveRange()
    .getCell(1, 1) // first selected cell in the range
    .getValue()
    .split(',') // convert the cell string into an array
    .map(str => str.trim()); // remove unwanted whitespace

  const optionsData = validOptions.map(option => {
    return {
      value: option,
      isSelected: selectedOptions.includes(option)
    }
  })

  return optionsData;
}

function setOptionsForCurrentCell(selectedOptions){
  const hasOptions = Array.isArray(selectedOptions) 
    && selectedOptions.length > 0
  const cellData = hasOptions
    ? selectedOptions.join(',') // creates a comma separated string
    : '';
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getCell(1, 1);
  cell.setValue(cellData);  
}
```

Then you create a Html file inside the script editor to render the dialog and pass the selected options back to the spreadsheet. See:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <? for (const option of optionsData) { ?>
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        class="option" 
        value="<?= option.value ?>" 
        <?= option.isSelected && "checked" ?>
      >
      <label><?= option.value ?></label><br>
    <? } ?>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <input 
        type="button" 
        value="all" 
        onclick="setAll('check')"
      />
      <input 
        type="button" 
        value="clear" 
        onclick="setAll('clear')" 
      />
      <input 
        type="button"
        value="cancel"
        onclick="google.script.host.close()"
      />
      <input 
        type="button"
        value="apply"
        onclick="apply()"
      />
    </div>
    <script>      
      function setAll(value) {
        const optionsEl = document
          .querySelectorAll(".option");
        for (const checkbox of optionsEl) {
          checkbox.checked = value === 'check';
        }
      }

      function apply(){
        const checkedEls = document
          .querySelectorAll(".option:checked");
        const selectedValues = [];
        for (const checkbox of checkedEls) {
          if (checkbox.checked) {
             selectedValues.push(checkbox.value);
          }
        }
        google.script.run
          .setOptionsForCurrentCell(selectedValues);
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That should work. If you want a step-by-step guide for this solution, check this [post](https://blog.melo.plus/posts/2020-05-18-multi-value-dialogs-in-google-sheets/).